# Cypress environment variable picking multiple values when executed from CLI. How to pass multiple environment variables in Cypress tests?

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cypress with Cucumber Preprocessor and Typescript
While I am running Cypress from CLI (not using the script object in package.json) and passing multiple env variable values, the first value is picking all the remaining comma-separated values when the test case is executed.
Eg: When I run the below command
command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --env URL1=https://testurl.com,URL2=https://testurl2.com --headed --browser chrome
```

URL getting picked in the script is "https://testurl.com,URL2=https://testurl2.com" but it should only pick "https://testurl.com".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you should be able to specify multiple environment variables as follows:

```
cypress run --env host=kevin.dev.local,api_server=http://localhost:8888/api/v1
```

You can then access those in your tests like:

```
Cypress.env() // {host: 'kevin.dev.local', api_server: 'http://localhost:8888/api/v1'}
Cypress.env('host') // 'kevin.dev.local'
Cypress.env('api_server') // 'http://localhost:8888/api/v1/'
```

I have taken the examples above right [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4-env) from the Cypress Docs.

At first sight your code looks correct, maybe you can check the variable names again and also try executing:

```
npx cypress run --headed --env host=kevin.dev.local,api_server=http://localhost:8888/api/v1
```

Comment: Using npx worked for me. Thank you so much for the help.